# get Dropdown selected value SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, development, asp.net

I have a choice column in my SharePoint list called `Njësia`, I have created a dropdown in my solution and I want to retrieve selected value from dropdown list.

I have a label called `Label1` and I want to represent the selected item in dropdown list.

I have the following code:

```
SPFieldChoice YearChoice = (SPFieldChoice)sampleList.Fields["Njësia"];
        for (int i = 0; i < YearChoice.Choices.Count; i++)
        {
            DropDownList4.Items.Add(YearChoice.Choices[i].ToString());
        }  
  string selectedvalyear = DropDownList4.SelectedValue;
  Label1.Text = selectedvalyear;
```

I also tried this line:

```
string selectedvalyear = DropDownList4.Text;
```

The result of `Label1` is null or it displays only the first item in dropdown I have enable autopostback but nothing happens Please help me!

Comment: @AakashMorya I am using it but because the fact that dropdown gets items directly from SP list I am thinking it has no value

Comment: Just do one thing. Debug this code using worker process and find whether value in DropDownList4 is set or not?

Comment: Look @AakashMorya if I use your code it shows me only the first item of my dropdown and when I try to change it is not going to be changed

Comment: If you are selecting the value from dropdown in GUI then surely you will get value. See my updated answer

Comment: Maybe my guide "How to populate a list column" could help: https://afrait.com/blog/auto-populate-list-column-en/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**To get a SharePoint Choice Field value**

```
SPFieldChoice myChoicesfield = (SPFieldChoice)list.Fields["FieldName"];
        for (int i = 0; i < myChoicesfield.Choices.Count; i++)
          {
            DropDownListName.Items.Add(myChoicesfield.Choices[i].ToString());
          }
```

**To get a SharePoint Multiple Choice Field value**

```
SPFieldMultiChoiceValue itemValue = 
new SPFieldMultiChoiceValue(item["FieldName"].ToString());
foreach (string choice in itemValue)
{
// value is in choice
}
```

> **Ref**: [Get and Set a SharePoint Multiple Choice Field Value in C#](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/get-and-set-a-sharepoint-multiple-choice-field-value-using-server-object-model-c/)

**Regarding your code**

normally, the above code retrieves only one item or null because the selected value only gets one value if the dropdown has items or null if it's empty.

So try to get the count of dropdown list items to make sure that you have already retrieved the data properly using the above code before you assign the selected value to the label, in Selected Index Changed Event don't forget to surround your code with

```
If(!Page.IsPostBack)
{
Label.text = dropdownlist.Text;
}
```

> **P.S:** The issue may not be tied to retrieving values but rather to the scenarios in your code.

Comment: can't make your code to work

Comment: Why ?!! it's normal that your above code retrieves only one item or null because the selected value only get one value if the dropdown has items or null if it's empty ,so that try to get the count of dropdown list items to make sure my above code bound to the drop-down list or not ! before you assign the selected value to the label, might be the problem is not related retrieving the value rather than your code scenarios !

Comment: I cannot use `SPFieldMultiChoiceValue` it provides me an error

Comment: Are you checked this >> SPFieldChoice myChoicesfield = (SPFieldChoice)list.Fields["FieldName"];
        for (int i = 0; i < myChoicesfield.Choices.Count; i++)
          {
            DropDownListName.Items.Add(myChoicesfield.Choices[i].ToString());
          }

Comment: Kindly,Read my answer again I provided you with one choice and multiple choice also choice field is also drop-down list but you only changed it's style view to show as drop-down list instead of choice but the data type is same

Comment: Ok let me try your solution, I really appreciate it

Comment: I have the same code you just provided

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42377/discussion-between-joun-martin-and-nderon-hyseni).

Comment: @jouan Can you help me please?

Comment: I am ready Nderon and wait you more are you there ?

Answer (score 3):

From where `DropDown1` came? In your code you are adding items in `DropDownList4` and you are trying to access the value from `DropDown1`.

Your code should be like:

```
string selectedvalyear = Convert.ToString(DropDownList4.SelectedItem);
Label1.Text = selectedvalyear;
```

If you want to change the value of `Lable1` from dropdown every time when you change item, then you must create a `SelectedIndexChanged` Event of DropDown and write above code in that event.

**Solution-2:**

You should write your code in :

```
If(!Page.IsPostBack)
{
SPFieldChoice YearChoice = (SPFieldChoice)sampleList.Fields["Njësia"];
        for (int i = 0; i < YearChoice.Choices.Count; i++)
        {
            DropDownList4.Items.Add(YearChoice.Choices[i].ToString());
        }  
  string selectedvalyear = DropDownList4.SelectedValue;
  Label1.Text = selectedvalyear;
}
```

Comment: It was a mistake I updated the question but still not working

Comment: Just do one thing. Debug this code using worker process and find whether value in DropDownList4 is set or not?

Comment: I am retrieving the choices in my page_load and for each time that I try to chose another item in my dropdown list it selects only the first item nothing else!

Comment: Then you must iterate it and go with selectedIndex and retrieve the value using DropDownList4.Items[YourIndex].Value; Your code is written in such a way it will always give you first item only. What you want to display in Label1?

Comment: still not working :(

Comment: Do you want to append all values in Labe1?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42296/discussion-between-aakash-morya-and-nderon-hyseni).

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you write dropdown change event. Keep autopostback property to true.

In dropdown change event of your dropdown write below code.

```
protected void DropDownList4_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                Label1.Text = DropDownList4.SelectedItem.Text;
        }
```

This will show display value of selected choice

You can also use:

```
  Label1.Text = DropDownList4.SelectedItem.Value;
```

This will show value (not display value) of selected choice

Your HTML block should look like:

`<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList4" runat="server" Height="22px" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList4_SelectedIndexChanged">`

Comment: Unfortunately only the first item is being selected and when i try to change the value, it does not change it keeps only the first value

Comment: can you show HTML block of you dropdown control

Comment: `<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList4" runat="server" Height="22px" AutoPostBack="true">

</asp:DropDownList>`

Comment: dude, you haven't used used the solution I provided.

Comment: ? I don`t understand what should I do Gaurravs?

Comment: I updated my answer. copy the method to your code behind. and update HTML block with one I provided

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42299/discussion-between-nderon-hyseni-and-gaurravs).